# Microsoft Azure Storage Service APIs removal on december 2015

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

As a Microsoft Azure services client, I received earlier today the following mail: http://aka.ms/Qga48e.

I was wondering how I could migrate my Blob storage without services disruption to use the latest Azure File Storage service.

Anybody has already performed this action? Any feedbacks will be welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that it would be necessary. Besides Azure Blob Service and Azure File Service serve different purposes all together and the things you could do with blob service can't be done through file service.

As mentioned in the newsletter, what you should try to do is upgrade your client applications to make use of latest version of storage client library. If you're using an older version of library (< 2.0), there would be some pain in migration but migrating from 2.0 to 4.x (currently latest version) should be rather painless.

Next thing you should look into is the [`default service version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.shared.protocol.serviceproperties.defaultserviceversion.aspx) of your storage account services. If you're using .Net storage client library, you can fetch it via [`GetServicePropertiesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.getservicepropertiesasync.aspx) method. You can update the default service version using [`SetServicePropertiesAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.setservicepropertiesasync.aspx) method.

You may also find this link helpful about understanding storage service versioning: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894041.aspx.

**UPDATE: 13-DEC-2014**

Azure Storage Team has published a blog post which talks more about this issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/08/05/microsoft-azure-storage-service-version-removal.aspx.

Comment: I am currently using v3 of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage dll, but when looking at my $logs the requests I can see "2009-09-19" there. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: What logs are telling you is that your storage service version is older. My recommendation would be to update it using `SetServicePropertiesAsync` method. You may find this link helpful in understanding how versioning is supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722534.aspx (look under section titled `Requests Authenticated with Shared Key/Shared Key Lite and Anonymous Requests`). HTH.

Answer (score 2):

The Storage Service REST API is *not* being removed. There are several versions of the API, from over the years. Older versions of the REST API (prior to the 2012-02-12 version) are being retired. But it's definitely not going away, and neither is the Azure Storage service.

Different versions of the SDKs (across the various language stacks) and command-line tools (PowerShell, CLI) may be using one of the older versions. If you're using the current versions of SDKs and command-line tools, this has no effect on you.

Consider how many versions there have been (all tracked [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn722534.aspx), and all listed in the page you linked to in your answer:

- 2014-02-14 (current)
- 2013-08-15
- 2012-02-12
- 2011-08-18
- 2009-09-19
- 2009-07-17
- 2009-04-14

If you're using an older version of an SDK or command-line tool, there's a chance that, in Dec. 2015, it won't work as expected anymore, as the underlying version will have been retired. So, essentially you have until December 2015 to update your Azure projects if needed.